# Debugging Tcl/tk application for Windows

Tags: debugging, tcl, tk-toolkit, decompiling, patch

Does it possible debug Tcl/tk application for Windows, without the source code? The application have no support and there is no source code available. There is error shown during one of operation. Is it possible to find what cause an error and whether error can be fixed by patching code?

Answer (score 1):

It's very difficult without the source code, as it is at the level of the source code where you'd need to make the patch. If the code is exposing itself via the `send` command mechanism (or the `comm` package) you can probably make a bit of progress (as there's quite good introspection capabilities in Tcl by default, so `info commands`, `info vars` and `info body` may help, along with many other `info` commands and some introspectors that are elsewhere too), but it's still really difficult, particularly if you don't understand the internal structure of the code. OTOH, I wouldn't expect a production application to expose itself this way; typically you disable that sort of thing when outside development.

A standard debugger like gdb won't help, especially with the Tcl 8.6 non-recursive runtime. (Tcl applications in that environment just tend to show up as effectively “doing stuff”; there's nothing to really indicate how it hangs together.)

But the first thing to check is whether you actually have the source code. It's possible that the code has just been packaged together as a [Starpack](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3663) and that you can use a tool like [sdx](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3411) to extract the things you need to make changes in. But you aren't guaranteed to succeed at that; if the code was compiled/obscured with a commercial tool like the [TDK](http://www.activestate.com/tcl-dev-kit), you really don't have the source and can't really do much about it. (By the same general principles that mean that DRM doesn't work well, it's possible to decompile the `.tbc` files that the TDK produces, but that's really a last-ditch thing to do as it is technically illegal in some jurisdictions, morally rather dodgy, and inclined to produce really awful output.) Can you contact the original author(s) of the code instead? If that works, it'll be cheaper and simpler…

If you've actually got the human-readable code, even if packaged with sdx, then you can do a lot more.

Comment: How to check that PE exe code has been packaged together as a Starpack? On Linux `strings file.exe` command show a lot of details, but not sure.